# How can i use next() or current() in laravel eloquent returned array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am building reservation system and I am programming fucntions that are recursive. Because of that I need to use php functions next(), and current() in PHP. The problem is that if I have array of all records in eloquent, it just doesnt work. It works in every other array, so my guess is that the internal pointer is not set, but then reset() function didnt also help.

The problem is when I call eloquent model in laravel to get all results from table like this:

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

And then I echo or return (doesnt matter) current($posts), I get the same result as if I returned $posts (whole array)

When I try to call this:

```
next($posts);
return current($posts);
```

Or:

```
prev($posts);
return current($posts);
```

I have an error:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

Please can anyone help me with this problem? if I make the same array and return it eloquent array and this new created array are same but if I use current on the eloquent one, it doesnt work. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Post::all()` returns a Collection, not an array. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections You could `toArray()` it, but I suspect there'd be a better way of handling this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$posts = Post::all(); // returns a collection
```

You want

```
$posts = Post::all()->toArray();
```

You can then call `current($posts)` or `next($posts)` or `prev($posts)` or `end($posts)`.

But as you have a collection, you could always use laravel's collection methods such as `first`, `last`, `each`, `filter`, `map`, `reduce` etc.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#available-methods

Comment: thank you very much, i guess this is pretty fundamental thing, so i suppose i should learn this before anything else, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve first row: `Post::first()`

To convert collection to array: `Post::all()->toArray()`

```
$posts = Post::all()->toArray();
current($posts);
next($posts);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code:

```
$models = User::whereIn('name',$names)->get()->getIterator();

while ( $record = $models->current() )
{
    ...
    $models->next();
}
```